# Implement FormArray in a Dynamic Form - Angular

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular-reactive-forms

I am basing my dynamic form from [this article](https://juristr.com/blog/2017/10/demystify-dynamic-angular-forms/#kudo). I need to create a FormArray field but I keep getting errors on my implementation. The code below shows the typescript code and the snippet for the switch case for array respectively. I am getting the error `Error: Cannot find control with path: 'anArray -> anArray'`. What is wrong with my FormArray setup for a dynamic form?

```js
form: FormGroup;

ngOnInit() {
  // remap the API to be suitable for iterating over it
  this.objectProps =
    Object.keys(this.dataObject)
    .map(prop => {
      return Object.assign({}, {
        key: prop
      }, this.dataObject[prop]);
    });
  var str = JSON.stringify(this.objectProps, null, 2);

  // setup the form
  const formGroup = {};
  for (let prop of Object.keys(this.dataObject)) {
    if (prop == "anArray") {
      formGroup[prop] = this.fb.array([
        [''],
      ])
    } else {
      formGroup[prop] = new FormControl(this.dataObject[prop].value || '', this.mapValidators(this.dataObject[prop].validation));
    }
  }

  this.form = new FormGroup(formGroup);
}

addFormInput(field) {
  const form = new FormControl('');
  ( < FormArray > this.form.controls[field]).push(form);
}

removeFormInput(field, i) {
  ( < FormArray > this.form.get(field)).removeAt(i);
}
```

```html
<div *ngSwitchCase="'array'">
  <label>{{prop.key}}</label>
  <div formArrayName="{{prop.key}}" [id]="prop.key">
    <br>
    <div formArrayName="{{prop.key}}" *ngFor="let item of form.get(prop.key).controls; let i = index;">
      <div [formGroupName]="i">
        <input [formControlName]="prop.key" [placeholder]="prop.label">
      </div>
      <div>
        <button type="button" class="btn" (click)="removeFormInput(prop.key, i)">x</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div>
    <button id="btn-add" type="button" class="btn" (click)="addFormInput(prop.key)">Add</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Sample data entry below

```js
export const person = {
  name: {
    label: 'Name',
    value: 'Juri',
    type: 'text',
    validation: {
      required: true
    }
  },
 anArray: {
    label: 'Name',
    value: 'Juri',
    type: 'array',
    validation: {
      required: true
    }
  },
  age: {
    label: 'Age',
    value: 32,
    type: 'text'
  },
  gender: {
    label: 'Gender',
    value: 'M',
    type: 'radio',
    options: [
      { label: "Male", value: 'M'},
      { label: "Female", value: 'F'}
    ]
  }, 
  city: {
    label: 'City',
    value: '39010',
    type: 'select',
    options: [
      { label: "(choose one)", value: ''},
      { label: "Bolzano", value: '39100'},
      { label: "Meltina", value: '39010'},
      { label: "Appiano", value: '39057'}
    ],
    validation: {
      required: true
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you also share your `dataObject` object?

Comment: @yurzui hello! updated for dataObject

Comment: What is your array supposed to be? Array of strings?

Comment: Here is your case https://ng-run.com/edit/BCfDIdaPqYjbt6MTBClU

Comment: @yurzui when i move it to my code i get ` formGroup expects a FormGroup instance. Please pass one in.
 formGroup expects a FormGroup instance. Please pass one in.`